# How do I check for any output from a Bluetooth Device or BLE device or a Beacon using Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Hi I am looking to get any output from a BLE device.I dont know how the device works.All the data I have is when I scan for any blue tooth device from an Android device it shows with name "Emums" and when I try to connect a message pops up saying "Pairing rejected by Emums".In an IOS device it is not even getting 
detected .I want to test with this BLE later move onto beacons where I will have more data about the beacons.I hope to get "ID" or "ANY CODE" from BLE so that i move forward .I want to develop an app using Unity with Csharp.

Comment: You need to write the code in Java as a plugin then communicate with the Java plugin with C#

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? A bunch of code that solves your problem? That's not the way Stack Overflow works. Google for "C# BLE" and you'll find a starting point. Come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: @Programmer I dont know JAVA. I am looking to develop an andrioid or IOS app with unity using C#. C# API's for only  windows  application?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yeah did google about it but dint get any expected result or any tutorials.Did get may results like u need to use JAVA plugin.Was looking to keep it simple

Comment: @zyonneo You need to learn Java then. No other way out. Now that you have mentioned iOS, you also need to learn Object-C or Swift then you can communicate to them with your C# code. An easy way out is buying a plugin from the assetstore if you don't feel like learning this. Flagging as a duplicate as they contain links to get you started.

Comment: @Programmer thanks... well will be stuck for a while....will try to learn that.

Comment: Or you could buy a plugin if you have an urgent deadline. Goodluck

Comment: @Programmer If I am using this github plugin(https://github.com/seiji/unity-bluetooth/blob/master/README.md)  how to get  the BLE device information.I got no clue.

Comment: @Programmer Which is the best plugin available for this issue in asset store?